# R Freezes when Plotting Spatial Data Frames

Tags: raster, r

I have run into a problem where anytime I try and plot a Spatial DataFrame in R, the console freezes, regardless of the size of the file.  I imagined this must be due to an issue with the path to one of the packages or the GDAL framework, but I have uninstalled and re-installed all of them and am still having an issue.  Any ideas?

Some example code, although I doubt that's the issue, as it is happening with all SpatialDataFrames:

```
library(raster)
india <- getData("GADM", country="IND", level=1)
plot(india)
```

I don't get an error, it just runs indefinitely until I manually force quit R.

Comment: Presumably this is stalled on getData rather than the plot, try downloading from the site manually

Comment: @mdsumner It seems to be an issue with all shapefiles.  I have also tried it with one downloaded from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip). I was just providing the raster code for reproducibility.

Comment: What is your machine spec? Does it fail with example data from rgdal or maptools?